# Rename line by line a file

Tags: python

I input, i have the following lines in my file.

```
...
VOAUT0000001712_19774.JPG   FRYW-1712-19774.jpg eab516afc1aaa10ad23edb5c15ae4ea4    1712    01

VOAUT0000001712_19775.JPG   FRYW-1712-19775.jpg 2715ceba8fd5c69b4ca6952e942a1a8a    1712    02 

VOAUT0000001712_19776.JPG   FRYW-1712-19776.jpg b1a0c4ec6160da3511e23c617517ff6f    1712    03 

VOAUT0000001713_19795.JPG   FRYW-1713-19795.jpg 56cd173c6e9436b19d39de214669cc53    1713    01 

VOAUT0000001713_19796.JPG   FRYW-1713-19796.jpg 271aa1b9ef2ac39c502a270c82b31fa3    1713    02 

VOAUT0000001713_19797.JPG   FRYW-1713-19797.jpg 667732a85660bebec168bc46b884d9b7    1713    03 

VOAUT0000001714_19763.JPG   FRYW-1714-19763.jpg d37770d6cde5639ce5db4e6a436498a8    1714    01 

VOAUT0000001714_19764.JPG   FRYW-1714-19764.jpg ce891ca4d4ea59c3a312a468bb0d4408    1714    02

VOAUT0000001714_19765.JPG   FRYW-1714-19765.jpg bd7fed521fe3997bf5c879d9d5ce942d    1714    03
...
```

I would like to modify my file line by line in order to have this

```
17124615_01_hd.jpg  /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1712-19774.jpg    eab516afc1aaa10ad23edb5c15ae4ea4

17124615_02_hd.jpg  /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1712-19775.jpg    2715ceba8fd5c69b4ca6952e942a1a8a

17124615_03_hd.jpg  /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1712-19776.jpg    b1a0c4ec6160da3511e23c617517ff6f 

17134615_01_hd.jpg  /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1713-19795.jpg    56cd173c6e9436b19d39de214669cc53 

17134615_02_hd.jpg  /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1713-19796.jpg    271aa1b9ef2ac39c502a270c82b31fa3

17134615_03_hd.jpg  /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1713-19797.jpg    667732a85660bebec168bc46b884d9b7 

17144615_01_hd.jpg  /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1714-19763.jpg    d37770d6cde5639ce5db4e6a436498a8 

17144615_02_hd.jpg  /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1714-19764.jpg    ce891ca4d4ea59c3a312a468bb0d4408

17144615_03_hd.jpg  /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1714-19765.jpg    bd7fed521fe3997bf5c879d9d5ce942d
```

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
def renameLineByLine():
    with open('/opt/data/photos.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            newname, file, path, checksum = line.split()
            if ..?? :
                try:
                    rename(...???)
                except OSError:
                    logger.error('Got a problem')
```

but I do not see how to rename each line with the new format ..?

Comment: Will there always be 3 of each number?

Comment: Also how are you getting this number: `17124615_01_hd.jpg`?

Comment: @RishavKundu in the first file a take the end of each line `1712    01` and i have a constant `4615`

Comment: @Mercer will there always be 3? Or can there be less or more?

Comment: @RishavKundu can there be less or more

Comment: Does the file have to be modified in place, or can you write to a new file?

Comment: @charrison i can write in a new file

Comment: Do you also have to rename the files, or just write that text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read in the file correctly: Skip empty lines and split for the correct values. There is no `path` where you expect one and you do not account for the two numbers at the end, which are crucial for the conversion.

Here I simply write all newly formatted lines into a new file, `photos_new.txt`. I hope this gets you started.

Note however, that your method name `renameLineByLine` as well as your `try/except` seem to hint that you also want to move/rename/do some work on your pictures. If that is the case, this answer will not be sufficient and you should try to elaborate a little bit more.

```
def renameLineByLine():
    new_lines = []
    path = '/opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/'
    with open('/opt/data/photos.txt', 'r') as fin, \ 
        open('/opt/data/photos_new.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if len(line) != 1:
                newname, file, checksum, no1, no2 = line.split()
                fout.write(" ".join([
                    "{}4615_{}_hd.jpg".format(no1, no2),
                    path + file, checksum, '\n'])
                )
            else:
                fout.write('\n')
```

Input:

```
VOAUT0000001712_19774.JPG   FRYW-1712-19774.jpg eab516afc1aaa10ad23edb5c15ae4ea4    1712    01

VOAUT0000001712_19775.JPG   FRYW-1712-19775.jpg 2715ceba8fd5c69b4ca6952e942a1a8a    1712    02 

VOAUT0000001712_19776.JPG   FRYW-1712-19776.jpg b1a0c4ec6160da3511e23c617517ff6f    1712    03 

VOAUT0000001713_19795.JPG   FRYW-1713-19795.jpg 56cd173c6e9436b19d39de214669cc53    1713    01 

VOAUT0000001713_19796.JPG   FRYW-1713-19796.jpg 271aa1b9ef2ac39c502a270c82b31fa3    1713    02 

VOAUT0000001713_19797.JPG   FRYW-1713-19797.jpg 667732a85660bebec168bc46b884d9b7    1713    03 

VOAUT0000001714_19763.JPG   FRYW-1714-19763.jpg d37770d6cde5639ce5db4e6a436498a8    1714    01 

VOAUT0000001714_19764.JPG   FRYW-1714-19764.jpg ce891ca4d4ea59c3a312a468bb0d4408    1714    02

VOAUT0000001714_19765.JPG   FRYW-1714-19765.jpg bd7fed521fe3997bf5c879d9d5ce942d    1714    03
```

Output:

```
17124615_01_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1712-19774.jpg eab516afc1aaa10ad23edb5c15ae4ea4 

17124615_02_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1712-19775.jpg 2715ceba8fd5c69b4ca6952e942a1a8a 

17124615_03_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1712-19776.jpg b1a0c4ec6160da3511e23c617517ff6f 

17134615_01_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1713-19795.jpg 56cd173c6e9436b19d39de214669cc53 

17134615_02_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1713-19796.jpg 271aa1b9ef2ac39c502a270c82b31fa3 

17134615_03_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1713-19797.jpg 667732a85660bebec168bc46b884d9b7 

17144615_01_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1714-19763.jpg d37770d6cde5639ce5db4e6a436498a8 

17144615_02_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1714-19764.jpg ce891ca4d4ea59c3a312a468bb0d4408 

17144615_03_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/FRYW-1714-19765.jpg bd7fed521fe3997bf5c879d9d5ce942d
```

Answer (score 1):

All the information you need to generate the lines is already provided. Thanks to @SebastianHöffner for pointing out the obvious.

```
out = open('output.txt','w')

for line in open('data.txt'):
    if len(line) != 1:
        a, b, c, d, e = line.split()
        l = d + '4615_'+ e + '_hd.jpg /opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/' + b + '  '+ c     
        out.write(l + '\n')
    else:
        out.write('\n')

out.close()
```

Comment: The numbers you are worried about are given in the input file, even with zeros. You can just use those.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
   with open('1.txt','r') as inF:
    with open('12.txt', 'w') as outF:

        for line in inF:
            if line not in ('\n','\r\n'):
                t = []
                s = line.split()
                t.append(s[3]+'4615_'+s[4]+'_hd.'+s[0].split('.')[1].lower())
                t.append('/opt/AutoPrivilege/client/photos/' + s[1])
                t.append(s[2]+'\n')
                outF.write(' '.join(t))

            else:
                outF.write(line)
```